# Xcode 9 Different Files Same Window

Tags: xcode

Does anyone know how to open two files in the same Xcode9 window (via tabs). This used to be so easy and intuitive, but it seems Apple has broken this functionality entirely.

I have used the Preference -> Navigation options and they have absolutely no affect on the behavior of the application.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about tabs..., but I think that is because there is an easier way to open a second file on the same window...

1. Go to the file navigator
2. Search for the file you want to open
3. Option + Double click it and you will get a second editor for that file on the same window.

NOTE - My preferences are:

a. Preferences -> Navigation -> Optional Navigation = Uses Single Assistant Editor

b. Preferences -> Navigation -> Double Click Navigation = Uses Separate Window